# Why can't I reference a user defined type field when using nested queries?

Tags: sql, oracle, types, ora-00904

So I have the following user defined type in my oracle database:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE METRIC_IMPERIAL_DISTANCE AS OBJECT
(
  METERS_FEET INTEGER,
  CENTIMETERS_INCHES INTEGER,
  FRACTION NUMBER
)
```

I can do the following:

```
SELECT t_id, get_distance_breakdown (h.height, h.unit_of_measure_id) height_breakdown
        FROM   heights h
```

and even

```
SELECT t_id, get_distance_breakdown (h.height, h.unit_of_measure_id).meters_feet height_meters_feet
        FROM   heights h
```

but the following fails with a ORA-00904: "HEIGHT_BREAKDOWN"."METERS_FEET": invalid identifier error:

```
SELECT t_id, height_breakdown.meters_feet
FROM   (SELECT t_id, get_distance_breakdown (h.height, h.unit_of_measure_id) height_breakdown
        FROM   heights h);
```

What gives?  If there isn't some simple and obvious work-around for this then that decimates much of what would be useful about oracle's user defined types.   I feel like I must be missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe Oracle needs an alias for the in-line view:

```
SELECT v.t_id, v.height_breakdown.meters_feet
FROM   (SELECT t_id, get_distance_breakdown (h.height, h.unit_of_measure_id) height_breakdown
        FROM   heights h) v;
```